# opengl - sub surface scatering - texture space diffustion

Tags: opengl

I would have a question to http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch16.html Example 16-5. A Vertex Program to Unwrap a Model and Perform Diffuse Lighting

```
struct a2v {
  float4 pos     : POSITION;
  float3 normal  : NORMAL;
  float2 texture : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct v2f {
  float4 hpos     : POSITION;
  float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
  float4 col      : COLOR0;
};

v2f main(a2v IN,
         uniform float4x4 lightMatrix)
{
  v2f OUT;

  // convert texture coordinates to NDC position [-1, 1]
  OUT.hpos.xy = IN.texture * 2 - 1;
  OUT.hpos.z = 0.0;
  OUT.hpos.w = 1.0;

  // diffuse lighting

  float3 N = normalize(mul((float3x3) lightMatrix, IN.normal));
  float3 L = normalize(-mul(lightMatrix, IN.pos).xyz);
  float diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0);
  OUT.col = diffuse;

  OUT.texcoord = IN.texture;
  return OUT;
}
```

ligthMatrix is used to transform the vertex positions (IN.pos). But i don´t understand, why it is allowed, to use this transformation matrix also to transform the vertex-normals (IN.normal). I thought normals would need an other special transformation matrix.?.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i don´t understand, why it is allowed, to use this transformation matrix also to transform the vertex-normals (IN.normal).

It's a short-cut. One that only works in certain situations.

The correct matrix to use is the inverse/transpose of the position transformation matrix. However, the transpose of a rotation matrix is it's *inverse*. And the inverse of an inverse is the original. Therefore, if you *know* that your position matrix contains only rotation (and translation, which we ignore for normals), then you can just use the matrix as-is.

The danger of this is if you *forget* that you've made this assumption, then start deciding to use scaling transformations for your positions.

Comment: Sounds interesting :) Will take some time till i really understand this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`(float3x3) lightMatrix` is a 3x3 matrix, which basically just encodes the rotation. You need a 4x4 matrix to do translations.

You rotate the normals so that they make sense in scene space (i.e. so that they rotate as the object rotates), but since the matrix is lacking the translation component they will remain the same size as they were originally(if they are normalized, they will remain normalized).

Comment: I thought i would always need a transpose inverse transformation matrix to transform normals. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/ : "Therefore the correct matrix to transform the normal is the transpose of the inverse of the M matrix."